# shell scripting process substitution <() inside command substitution $()

Tags: bash

I have a command with an output of 1 that is something like:

```
cmp -bl <(cmp -bl <(echo ABCDEF) <(echo ABDCEF)| wc -l) <(echo 0) |wc -l
```

I need to compare the command output with a value inside an if statement:

```
if [ $(cmp -bl <(echo ABCDEF) <(echo ABDCEF)| wc -l) = "1" ]; then ...
```

There error that I have is syntax related: syntax error near unexpected token ('

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net. tip `[` is a command so it needes a white space in between whatever is there. It just needs a closing `]`

Comment: Do not modify your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.  Do present code that reproduces the behavior you claim, which neither your original nor your revised code does for me.

Comment: The explanation for that (impossibility to reproduce behavior) has been given briefly in a comment of my answer: ibna is using /bin/sh not /bin/bash. There is a syntax error (exactly the one given in the question) when running that with /bin/sh. 
Reason is that <(...) syntax is bash-specific. In /bin/sh, you need to explicitly create named pipes, and redirect subprocess output to them, to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave a space after `[` and before `]`. `[` is an actual command similar to `test`. You need to separate the command from its parameters. `]` is not a command but syntax rules for parameters of `[` command requires it to be separated as well.

```
if [ $(cmp -bl <(cmp -bl <(echo ABCDEF) <(echo ABDCEF)| wc -l) <(echo 0) |wc -l) = "1" ]; then ...
```

Comment: I disagree with the statement "bash can't parse it correctly".  The command `if [$(...) = "1"]` is correctly parsed by bash, and (assuming the output of `$(...)` is `1`)  bash attempts to execute the command `[1` with the arguments `= ` and `1]`.  That `[1` is not a valid command in the user's PATH or a valid function does not make this a parsing problem.  It may be true that bash parses this differently than the author expects, but that also does not make this a parsing problem.

Comment: the problem is not related to the space, I simply forgot to add it in the example I posted

Comment: @BeneaIonut it is working for me. Which version of bash are you using?

Comment: @WilliamPursell right. I have updated the answer per your comment.

Comment: 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: With the new version of your question, plus comments you made, answer is straightforward.
Your code (the one in the current version of your question) is totally OK. It works fine on all my computers with bash.
But it is bash.
Not sh.

If you use it with /bin/sh (as you said you were doing in one of your comments), then, the error you get is

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The unexpected parenthesis here is the one of the `<(...)` syntax. This is bash specific syntax. /bin/sh cannot use pip/process substitution.

Understand that <(command) syntax is a special substitution. It runs command in another process, with output redirected to a pipe, whose filename is substituted to the <(command) part. `echo <(ls)` for examples displays something like `/dev/fd/63`, Which is a named pipe, a "file" whose "content" is the result of `ls` (even tho it is not a file, and it as no content. But reading /dev/fd/63 is reading the output of ls. It is quite useful, even if most of the time, you don't need it. But it is quite recent (well, maybe one or two decades. But it didn't exist when I learned sh/bash), and not part of /bin/sh.

So answer is: you need bash. You can't do that in /bin/sh

If you want to use cmp with the output of two commands, and you really can't just use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`, the simpler (and less efficient) solution would be to use temp files to store the result of the commands first (hoping that those commands do not produces gigabytes of output), and compare them.

Or, you could reproduce a quite similar behavior with named pipes.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
mknod /tmp/pipe1.$$ p
mknod /tmp/pipe2.$$ p
echo ABCDEF > /tmp/pipe1.$$ &
echo ABCxEF > /tmp/pite2.$$ &
if [ $(cmp -bl /tmp/pipe1.$$ /tmp/pite2.$$ | wc -l) = "1" ]; then
    echo One and only one diff
fi
rm /tmp/pipe1.$$
rm /tmp/pipe2.$$
```

It does roughly the same
The `echo stuff > /tmp/pipe1.$$ &`
for a `echo stuff` process (replace echo with whatever command you want). Whouse output is redirected in named pipe /tmp/pipe1.$$ we created in the first line.
(the .$$ suffix, is just to ensure that no other process could use the same /tmp/pipe1 name, since $$ is the pid of our process)
Then you have a quite classical `if [ $(cmp /tmp/pipe1.$$ /tmp/pipe2.$$ | wc -l) ]` in which, cmp is simply called with two files names, that happen to be named pipes (exactly as with <(...) after all)

But again, that is only if you have a very good reason to want a pure sh (not bash) solution. In which case you should also edit your question to remove the 'bash' tag.

================= Old answer ==========================

This seems very convoluted to me. For example the usage of cmp foo <(echo 0)
to compare the content of foo (foo itself being the result of a wc -l on a cmp) to 0.
But I surmise that you already understand that, that you understand that this is a Rube-Goldberg contraption instead of "== 0", and you understand that each <() fork a process, and return a name of pipes from this process (it has to be used when you need to pass a filename containing the result of an execution to  command).

If not, you should explain what you are really trying to do, because, even replacing the <(echo ...) by real commands (I also surmise those are just examples), there is no way those several stages of cmp and wc are the correct way.

That being said, just add a space around [ and ], and it will do exactly what you intended. (edit: as already said by others in faster reply and comments. I type too long answers... I do not delete this answer, because the preamble may be relevant)

EDIT: to reply more on the usage part

- No need, as seen in comments, for two layers of wc -l (one is already a strange way, but if it works...)
- Be careful of how you compare things.

  - Mine (in comments), using `==` works only in linux, because wc output is a string of digits, with nothing more. It doesn't on mac, because of heading spaces. So    `1` is not the same as `1`.
  - Yours, is the same. But since you used `[` instead of `[[`, `[` being and external command, while `[[` is bash syntax (`[[` is better: no fork of a process), the spaces of    `1` are lost during the passing of the argument to `[` command
  - the cleanest solution is probably to use -eq which compares the integers, regardless of how they are printed.

So, altogether

```bash
if [[ $(cmp -bl <(echo string1) <(echo string2) | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]
then
   echo one and only one difference
fi
```

should work.
Again, not sure it is the fastest, nor the shortest, nor the most elegant solution. But as long as nobody provides a better one...

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to compare 2 different strings (every one being the result of a command). I need to get the number of different characters between the 2 strings. If the number is 1, then an action should be performed.

Comment: Well, then you don't need a second layer of cmp | wc.

Comment: ``if [[ $(cmp -bl <(command1) <(command2) | wc -l) == 1 ]]; then actiion; fi`` is convoluted enough :)

Comment: I am pretty sure there are simpler solutions, but none I can think of right now.

Comment: You're right, the second cmp | wc is not needed but still I have the same syntax error even in the form you suggested

Comment: I don't.
```if [[ $(cmp -bl <(echo abcd) <(echo abcd) | wc -l) == 1 ]]; then echo one; fi``` prints nothing (and terminate with no error)
```if [[ $(cmp -bl <(echo abcd) <(echo aBCd) | wc -l) == 1 ]]; then echo one; fi``` prints nothing neither (two differences)
```if [[ $(cmp -bl <(echo abcd) <(echo abCd) | wc -l) == 1 ]]; then echo one; fi``` prints "one". 
As intended, if I understood correctly

Comment: Can you try those examples? It should work. Well, with linux/bash

Comment: On my mac, for example, it doesn't. Because wc -l output contains spaces. So wc -l answer is " 1" not "1"

Comment: which you can solve by using -eq instead of == (comparison of integer. So never mind the spaces)

Comment: I am editing the post to includes those change

Comment: That is right, it works with bash (#!/bin/bash), the syntax error is only in shell ( #!/bin/sh)

Comment: With pure shell (but you said in another comment that you were using linux. I thought the last linux distro with pure sh died 20 years ago. I remember, indeed, that 20 years ago, I was careful not to publish code specific to bash, and to use only pure sh when I wasn't able to assume bash. Here, well, there is a "bash" tag on your question :-)...), so with pure sh, I doubt that <(...) works any way.

Comment: The rest (wc, cmp) has nothing to do with shell. They are external command. Their behaviour depends on the distro (the version of those commands that are installed). Such as the ``    1`` thing for wc with macos. So, on a given machine, whatever shell you use, it should be the same. The ``[[`` can then be replaced by `[` in pure sh. But the <(...) thing is a bash thing.

Comment: thank you for all you contribution, my question is clear now

Comment: The code of your current question works fine here. Then statement isn't executed as is. And is executed if I replace examples by, say ABCDEF and ABxDEF

Comment: I edited my answer for the new version of your question. Short answer: you can't use /bin/sh. But if you must, I provide you a way to do the same (run process, and use file descriptor of output stream of those process as arguments to cmp. Which is what bash-specific ``<(...)`` syntax does)